# I want to check the highest delta between 6 columns in a dataframe using as few loops as possible

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

POPESTIMATES are actual pop estimates through the year 2010-2015, and I want to get the highest delta between the number of years. So I have to check |POPESTIMATE2015-POPESTIMATE2014|, |POPESTIMATE2015 - POPESTIMIATE2014|...|POPESTIMATE2013-POPESTIMATE2010|... and then find the highest abs delta. 
Here is the method I wrote to do that, but I am receiving a cannot convert float Nan to integer error and it is too slow. I am sure there is a more efficient way to do that. Any ideas?

```
def question7():
c = census_df
c['delta'] = 0
c['delta_max'] = 0
x = 5
y = 0
for index, row in c.iterrows():
    while x > 0:
        while y > -1:
            c.loc[index, ['delta']] = (c.loc[index, ['POPESTIMATE201' + str(x)]] - c.loc[index, ['POPESTIMATE201' + str(y)]]).abs()
            if int(c.loc[index, ['delta']]) > int(c.loc[index, ['delta_max']]):
                c.loc[index, ['delta_max']] = c.loc[index, ['delta']]
            y -= 1
        x -= 1
return c['delta_max']
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and show your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe need [`numpy.ptp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(15, size=(5, 6)))
df[[1, 4]] *= -1
df.columns = ['POP{}'.format(i) for i in range(2010, 2016)]
df['delta_max'] = np.ptp(df.values, axis=1)
print(df)
   POP2010  POP2011  POP2012  POP2013  POP2014  POP2015  delta_max
0        8      -12        0        4       -1        2         20
1        5      -10        4        1       -4        1         15
2        1       -8        1       10      -10        5         20
3        0       -7        4        8      -13        4         21
4        1       -3        8        0      -12        2         20
```